# Using ImageDataGenerator with model.fit_generator()

Tags: keras

I am currently using this code for training:

```
for x, y in generator.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=10240):
    fit = model.fit(x, y[:, 0],
                    batch_size=1024,
                    epochs=10,
                    verbose=1,
                    validation_split=.3,
                    shuffle=True,
                    callbacks=[checkpoint]
                    )
```

How can I convert it to use `model.fit_generator()` and behave the same way?

Answer (score 0):

`gen = generator.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=10240)`

`model.fit_generator(gen, steps_per_epoch=number_of_samples//batch_size, ...)`

Comment: So is this the right answer? I have the kinda of same issue.My dataset is big so I used my own generator. My question now how I can use my own generator with ImageDataGenerator?

Comment: @W.Sam, I guess so. See (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit_generator) to make sure your generator outputs what is expected by `fit_generator`

Comment: My generator output is what is expected by fit_generator. But still didn't know how to combine this with ImageDataGenerator for augmentation purpose? I opened issue on my problem and give example of my own generator here,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51109013/using-imagedatagenerator-with-your-own-generator

Comment: I don't know how to do that. But does it make sense to have your data in directories and use `flow_from_directory ` (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_directory) to read them?