# Using ImageDataGenerator with your own generator

Tags: generator

I have large dataset that will not fit in memory and it has multiple inputs. So thats why I created my own generator. But then I wanted to augment my data by using [ImageDataGenerator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) I face problem. I don't know how to combine both generators.

What I have done till now is :

```
def data_gen(  batch_size= None, nb_epochs=None, sess=None):

    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(training_filenames)
    dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function_all)  
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size= 1000 + 4* batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size).repeat()
    iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
    next_element = iterator.get_next()

    for i in range(nb_epochs):
        sess.run(iterator.initializer)
        while True:
            try:
                next_val = sess.run(next_element)
                images_a = next_val[0][:, 0]
                images_b = next_val[0][:, 1]
                labels = next_val[1]
                yield  [images_a, images_b], labels
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:

              break

 mymodel = Model(input=[input_a, input_b], output=out)
 mymodel.compile(loss=loss_both_equal, optimizer=rms, metrics=['accuracy', auc_roc])
 data_gen_1 = data_gen(batch_size= batch_size, nb_epochs= 10, sess= sess)
 mymodel.fit_generator(generator= data_gen_1, epochs = epochs,
            steps_per_epoch=335, 
             callbacks=[tensorboard, alphaChanger])
```

So If I want to do some augmentation using DataImageGenerator, how I can combine my own generator with DataIamgeGenerator?